# When to know when I should put the parameters in the body or not?

Tags: rest

I was thinking about the most logical request for my api, while trying to think about `rest`, but I can't wrap my head around which one of these three choices is correct: what would be the best design for the request, supposing that I want to send `10` from some user triggering the request to `user2`?

1)

```
POST /pay
body: {"username": "user2", "amount": 10}
```

2)

```
POST /pay/users/user2
body: {"amount": 10}
```

3)

```
POST /pay/users/user2/10
```

I don't know how much information should be in the URL vs. how much information should be in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at [restful-api-guidelines](https://byrondover.github.io/post/restful-api-guidelines/)

You want to put an Canonical Identifier in the URL and any other data in the body. 
For a POST (which is used to create an new resource) the Canonical Identifier generaly does not yet exist therefor it doesn't need one. 
The server then creates one and returns it to the client in the location header.

If you mean to update instead of insert, PUT or PATCH should be used. If the username is your Identifier, then option 2 should be used. An identifier should in general not be editable.

Since your "adding" an new payment I would suggest using option 1. But I would call it payment and perhaps add more information about the payment.

Comment: Hi Edwin! Thank you for you answer, I will read that. Before I dive in, I thought of another option actually, what about `POST /users/user2/pay | body: {"amount": 10}` ?

Comment: See my edit. I would prefer option 1 over your new option. The link I provided also talks about your type of URLs, under "URL Structure"

Comment: Oh yeah, it makes sense to rename it to payment, as having `POST /pay` would be like having `POST /create_user` instead of `POST /users`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have many users and some functions that users can perform.

So your api could be like:

```
GET    /users                                        # get user list
POST   /users + {"name": "John"}                     # create user 
DELETE /users/{userId}                               # remove user
GET    /users/{userId}                               # get user by id

GET    /users/{userId}/payments                      # get users payments
POST   /users/{userId}/payments +  {"amount": 10}    # submit new payment

GET    /users/{userId}/payments/{paymentId}          # get users payment details
```

As you can see it is a very simple resource tree.